# why I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory when running on OSGi framework

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am new to OSGi and I made a method which will call the Google translate API. When I called that method in a main it is working fine. And also I used Eclipse for coding and exported the project into a jar file from Eclipse and installed it on the apache felix framework. When I start the bundle I get the following exceptions,
I added all the external jar files to build path also.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle EnglishToSinhalaServicePublisher [58].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2452)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:739)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:139)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:91)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:599)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:526)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:415)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.doCall(Pipe.java:416)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:229)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
        at englishtosinhalaservicepublisher.Activator.start(Activator.java:46)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:698)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2402)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory not found by EnglishToSinhalaServicePublisher [58]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
g!
```

Comment: Does your bundle import package `com.google.api.client.json`?

Comment: @NeilBartlett I did that. But after that I am getting org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve EnglishToSinhalaServicePublisher [59](R 59.0): missing requirement [EnglishToSinhalaServicePublisher [59](R 59.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.api.client.json) Unresolved requirements: [[EnglishToSinhalaServicePublisher [59](R 59.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.api.client.json)] , This error can you help with this please ?

Comment: Do you have a bundle that exports the package `com.google.api.client.json`?

Comment: No I don't. what have I tried in my application is just to implement producer consumer scenario and I have a package containing the services. In that package activator I am registering the services and in the subscriber package activator I am looking for the service and I am calling the methods which are in the service. So, for that I implemented the method that translates by using the google translate API. So, can you give me suggestion that where can I be gone wrong? And apart from this translation I have implemented some other services which are doing some calculations.They works fine.

Comment: It's quite simple. Your bundle depends on the package `com.google.api.client.json`. That means you need to import it with `Import-Package: com.google.api.client.json`, which you have done. Now that you have a bundle with that package as an import, you must have a corresponding bundle with that package as an export. You need to install that bundle into your OSGi Framework.

Comment: That means do I need to install the jar files to OSGi framework which I have added externally in eclipse ? (jar files that contains com.google.api.client.json like wise) and also in those jar file's manifest do I need to export my bundle? I am right?

Comment: The bundles that your bundle depends on need to be installed into the OSGi Framework. You install them in the same way you installed your own bundle. You should not edit the manifest of third-party JAR files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. From the answered you have given to me I got the idea what I need to do. So, I solved the issue. I created another plug in which will contain all the jars and and that plug in is exporting all the classes I need. And I used them in my plug in. So my previous problem solved

Comment: Okay you can do that but you are making your own life harder. Why not use bundles as bundles, rather than building your own super-bundle containing everything you depend on?

Comment: Yes, I need to try that one also :)